# Is $x\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ Riemann-integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x) = x\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ and $f(0)=0$,

Can we say $f(x)$ is Riemann-integrable?

I would say yes because the the only part at which $f(x)$ behaved oddly was at $x=0$, but that is taken care of.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You could directly say that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$. So $f$ is Riemann integrable on all closed intervals.